# Why using multiple factory classes?

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern

Isn't the purpose of the factory method is to help to get instances of subclasses which are chosen dynamically so that you might not call their constructors implicitly? Why then in some cases multiple factory classes are used for each of the subclasses? If I understand it correct, for each subclass you have to call the method of the corresponding factory so there's no reason to use a factory method here.

Answer (score 0):

1) you may have a distributed application where it makes sense for different developers to provide their own factory classes.

2) it is very usable in testing using dependency injection.

3) multiple factory classes can exist that implement different algorithms, but deliver the same type of data objects.

Classic NetBeans example:

> JEditorPane.registerEditorKitForContentType allows to register a kit
>   per mime type as it has been anticipated that there will be multiple
>   modules trying to register their own kits.

Comment: 1) messy code as a result? 2), 3) the same as with one factory

Comment: How can you achieve 3) with a single factory class? With a lot of the switch operators? Just curious.

Comment: different methods withing single factory, what's the problem?